# How to access ASP.NET website hosted in Google cloud windows instance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, networking, google-compute-engine, cloud-hosting, windows-server-2012-r2

I recently got [ASP.NET infrastructure on Google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/solution/click-to-deploy-images/aspnet?q=asp.net) for hosting an [ASP.NET MVC website](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

I have successfully hosted the website on **that virtual machine's [IIS](https://www.iis.net/)**. So, inside that machine, I can run the website on `localhost`.

The external IP of the virtual machine is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (masked for security purpose). I wanted to do something by which I can access the site on my [domain](http://nerdspal.com/) publicly.

**Problem:** It is supposed to be accessed on [nerdspal.com](http://nerdspal.com/). How do I access the website using browser?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Unsure what you're asking - if you have verified your web app as running, then it's all about [networking](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking). Assuming you've got that done properly (e.g. public access), then next step is DNS for whatever domain you want to point to your GCloud IP addresses...If this is too vague, it probably is (too broad a topic for SO)....

Comment: @EdSF - Thanks for the starting point. This is my first time ever interaction with clouds, so I'm a little scared. I'm updating my question to make things more clear.

Comment: @EdSF - this lead me to a [new question](http://serverfault.com/questions/711744/how-to-enable-incoming-world-wide-web-traffic-in-iis).

Comment: It's good to tinker - you'll learn a lot about "how to manage everything" - as you are going through right now :) When I tried Google Cloud a few months back (trial Windows beta), it reminded me of how it was when I also wore an IT hat :) Have you tried running IIS 8 _locally_? I think it will help if you did (bindings, hostname, app pool, etc.) - it's a bit more involved than just running Visual Studio where it does "everything" for you. You can apply what you learn to GGloud IIS setup.

Comment: @EdSF - your first comment was my answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per *[EdSf's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304683/edsf)* comment:

- The Virtual machine's IIS ports needs to be opened for WWW traffic by tinkering with [networking things](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking).
- DNS records needs to be [updated](https://serverfault.com/questions/171611/internal-dns-server-but-cant-access-externally-hosted-website) with [my domain provider](https://www.godaddy.com).